# iOS - attaching a PDF file: PDF ok in simulator folder, but corrupted when attached to email on device

Tags: ios, email, pdf, nsdata

Hopefully the title made sense. Here's my situation.

I have one PDF created in Pages then exported as a PDF. I then create another PDF within the app. I create the PDF file with this code:

```
- (void)makePDF:(NSString*)fileName :(NSDictionary*)dictResults
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    _strPDFJustCreated = fileName;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName:dictResults];
}

- (void)generatePdfWithFilePath:(NSString *)thefilePath :(NSDictionary*)dictResults
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);
    BOOL done = NO;

    do {
        ...whole lot of coding goodness
        done = YES;
    } while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Both files are attached to the email message with this code:

```
/**********Attach PDF Files**************/
//get path to pdf file
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strPDFFileName];

//convert pdf file to NSData
NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath];

//attach the pdf file
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:strPDFFileName];

//get path to pdf file
NSString* pdf2FilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OER_MarketingContent.pdf"];

//convert pdf file to NSData
NSData* pdf2Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdf2FilePath];

//attach the pdf file
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:pdf2Data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"OER_MarketingContent.pdf"];

[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

When I take a peak inside the app folder within the iPhone Simulator folder the pdf files are there, they are recognized by the OS as PDF files and I can open and read them. However, when I get an email message delivered (and don't laugh but we use Lotus Notes), I cannot preview the files I can't an error message saying there is no filter available, when I opt to open it (in Preview) it just hangs.

I use the same code in other apps with no problems. My guess then is that I am doing something different somewhere in my code. I can't see anything obvious so my question would be is there a way to test say NSData for success/failure prior to attaching the file or testing it post attachment but pre email?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);`.  Instead, use: `NSData * pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];`.

So, the whole thing should end up looking like:

```
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@email.com"]];
        [controller setSubject:@"PDFTEST"];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"Your text here" isHTML:NO];

NSData * pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
    NSString *testFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDFNAME"];
    [controller addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:testFileName];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This worked for me.  Let me know if you have any more questions or if this is unclear.  Thanks!